# MySQL complicated query | extracting a phrase from table of words

Tags: mysql

I'm working through MySQL connector in python on a project where I'm analyzing books.

I would gladly accept any help with my issue (explained below).

The relevant DB structures:

each **Word**, in each book, has its own word_id(primary key) and text.

each **Word_instance** has word_id, word_serial, offset in line, sentence number and so on...

the entity **Word_instance**'s word_serial is its offset from the beginning of the book.

each **Phrase** has its own id and text.

each **Phrase_word** has phrase_id and word_id(from above).

Right now, I'm trying to figure out how to build a query that will locate a phrase from the user in the database.

Words are a part of a phrase if they have consecutive word_serial and are in the same sentence.

so far I've managed to build the following mess of a query:

```
select book_id
     , word_txt
     , word_serial
     , sentence_serial
     , ROW_NUMBER() Over (partition by sentence_serial, book_id) as encounter_num
  from word
  join word_instance 
    on word.word_id = word_instance.word_id
  join word_in_phrase 
    on word.word_id = word_in_phrase.word_id
 where  phrase_id = %s 
 order 
    by book_id
     , sentence_serial
     , word_serial
```

In the following table image is the result set of said query.

let's say the user has entered the phrase: "I believe in cause".

in that case I would need to extract word_serial = 562, as it is the beginning said phrase.

can I accomplish such a task without extracting row by row and assessing whether the current row is part of the phrase and in the correct order?

In fact, there are way to many rows to examine outside of SQL to consider that a possibility.

I will appreciate your help immensely, as I'm stuck on this issue for far too long...

[image]

As requested, I'm uploading images of relevant DB entities:

[Word_in_phrase entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHfNl.png)

[Word_instance entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrkmE.png)

[word entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5wRp.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The full table structure will be useful, but in particular note that I don't think you've said which table column defines the order of the words in the phrase.

Comment: Thanks for providing more information. So you have no column that defines the order of the words in the phrases? Do we just assume the order the rows happen to be in the word_in_phrase table is the order? Can phrases cross sentences (i.e. if they appear sequentially by word_serial but have different sentence_serials)?

Comment: @EdmCoff I appreciate the response :) 

As you assumed correctly, I do not have a column that defines the order of the words in the phrase, but in case it is necessary I'll add one. so if you'll imagine such a column exists, can you produce a result set that returns the rows where such a phrase begins?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you also please specify your version of mysql? The query will probably be simpler in mysql 8 because of CTE/LEAD/LAG being available.

Comment: @EdmCoff It's 8.0.21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't the most efficient way of writing this, but I think it works in principle and you could tinker with it as you wanted. Note that I assumed phrases can't cross sentence boundaries (wi2.sentence_serial = wi1.sentence_serial) and I've assumed a column word_in_phrase.order_id exists that starts at 0 and increases by 1 for each word. I'm also assuming word_id increases by 1 each row. (You could make those assumptions true by using CTEs where that is true instead of the real tables).

```
with (
 SELECT *
 FROM word_in_phrase
 WHERE phrase_id = %s
) as phrase
select book_id
     , word_txt
     , word_serial
     , sentence_serial
  from word
  join word_instance wi1
    on word.word_id = word_instance.word_id
 where  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM phrase) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM word_instance wi2 INNER JOIN phrase on wi2.word_id = phrase.word_id WHERE wi2.book_id = wi1.book_id and wi2.sentence_serial = wi1.sentence_serial and wi2.word_id = wi1.word_id + phrase.order_id)
 order 
    by book_id
     , sentence_serial
     , word_serial
```

Alternatively, you might prefer something like

```
with (
 SELECT *
 FROM word_in_phrase
 WHERE phrase_id = %s
) as phrase
select wi1.book_id
     , word_txt
     , wi1.word_serial
     , wi1.sentence_serial
  from word
  join word_instance wi1
    on word.word_id = word_instance.word_id
  inner join word_instance wi2 
    on wi2.book_id = wi1.book_id and wi2.sentence_serial = wi1.sentence_serial
  INNER JOIN phrase 
    on wi2.word_id = phrase.word_id 
  WHERE wi2.word_id = wi1.word_id + phrase.order_id
  GROUP BY 
     wi1.book_id
     , word_txt
     , wi1.word_serial
     , wi1.sentence_serial
 HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM phrase)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I tweaked your answer a bit to suit my DB and it worked just great. 
Your answer reminded me I need to refresh my knowledge in SQL queries. 
Wish I could upvote  your answer, aside from "accepting", but my reputation took a hit with this question, and with it my upvote privilege was taken. 

Thanks again mate!